# How to add rounded borders to scaled image in ImageView

Tags: android

My view xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp" />
```

My drawbale xml with corner:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="6dp"
        android:color="#191970" />
    <padding
        android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

My code, where I add an image and scale it:

```
mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mImageView.setImageResource(mDeskCards.get(0).getDrawable()); // some .png file
mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

What I have vs what I need:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WPI3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a view with your drawable xml over the image you will get the rounded corner effect that you are looking for.

For clarification, you should have something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
     .... >

    <ImageView
        .... />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How to put it in LinearLayout?

Comment: By replacing "RelativeLayout" with "LinearLayout"

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple libraries to help you do that. The one I'd suggest is Glide. You'll find many tutorials across the web. To do what you want you can use this code

`Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(mImageView);`

Answer (score 0):

Using a normal ImageView the image will be always shown with squared corners

I solved it creating my own class extended from View, creating a clipping Path and in onDraw first drawing the border then calling  `canvas.clipPath(myClipPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);` and then drawing the image. That works also with circular or oval border.

If the border corners radius is small and the border stroke thick then you can try without clipping :  in onDraw first drawing the image and then the border over.

**ADDED:**

Derive a class from ImageView and use something like this:

```
    private Path clipPath;
    private RectF rect;
    private float radius = 20;


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        clipPath = new Path();
        rect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my library: [PowerfulImageView](https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView).
Just use it instead of the ImageView in your layout and set the shape to roundedRectangle or solidRoundedRectangle, and you can choose the color, width and radius of the border, all directly in xml (or via Java).

Basically, your view.xml shoud become:

```
<com.stefanosiano.powerfulimageview.PowerfulImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:piv_shape_mode="rounded_rectangle" />
```

Let me know if you have problems if you use it :)